# Grid - Obstacle / How to Calculate "Field of view"

Tags: algorithm, math, grid

My english is not my native language, I have no idea how title it, how to explain it clearly and not sure if it's the right term. I've tried to search on google first but for the reason quoted above, I couldn't find anything related.

Could you guys first please check the imgur album : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoPJk.jpg

So...

- Black square is an "obstacle"
- Red Square is a "player"
- Grey square are "area where player is not able to see"

Depending on the distance of the player from the obstacle, the player can see more or less "things"

Is there a general formula to determine the area that he can see or can't see ?
Or I have to write a unique formula depending on the player position relative to the obstacle

I'm sorry If what I wrote doesn't make sense
Thanks for your help

EDIT :

point player(5, 0);

point obstacle(4, 2);

```
.....o...
.........
....@....
.........
.....#...
.....##..
.....###.
.....####
......###
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs a little work. I'll say the steps to make it work:

`(1)` Let's define the player position `p` and the obstacle position `o`.

We know we want to paint a "triangle" after the obstacle.

`(2)` Let's define the angle according to proximity.

The nearer, the bigger the angle is, so I set the angle to 45 if the distance is 1 and it decreases as the player gets further from the obstacle. The angle is `5 + (max(0, 50 - distance * 10))`. You can tune this angle.

`(3)` Let's build a big triangle. The first vertex is the obstacle. Then, throw a big line from the player through the obstacle. Rotate this line around the obstacle half angle clockwise (to get the second vertex) and half angle anti-clockwise (to get the third vertex), as shown in the image:[image]

`(4)` Lastly, iterate to the matrix and for each position, ask if that coordinates are inside the triangle.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct point{
    float x, y;
    point(){}
    point(float x, float y){this->x = x; this->y = y;}
    //point(int x, int y){this->x = x; this->y = y;}
};

point rotate(point pivot, float angle, point p, bool clockwise){
    float s = sin(angle);
    float c = cos(angle);

    p.x -= pivot.x;
    p.y -= pivot.y;

    if(clockwise){
        return point(p.x * c + p.y * s + pivot.x, -p.x * s + p.y * c + pivot.y);
    }
    else{
        return point(p.x * c - p.y * s + pivot.x, p.x * s + p.y * c + pivot.y);
    }
}

float triangleArea(point p1, point p2, point p3) {         //find area of triangle formed by p1, p2 and p3
   return abs((p1.x*(p2.y-p3.y) + p2.x*(p3.y-p1.y)+ p3.x*(p1.y-p2.y))/2.0);
}

bool inside(point p1, point p2, point p3, point p) {     //check whether p is inside or outside
   float area = triangleArea (p1, p2, p3);          //area of triangle ABC
   float area1 = triangleArea (p, p2, p3);         //area of PBC
   float area2 = triangleArea (p1, p, p3);         //area of APC
   float area3 = triangleArea (p1, p2, p);        //area of ABP

   return abs(area - area1 + area2 + area3) < 1;        //when three triangles are forming the whole triangle
}

char m[9][9];

point player(4, 0);
point obstacle(4, 2);

float angle(){
    float dist = sqrt(pow(player.x - obstacle.x, 2) + pow(player.y - obstacle.y, 2));
    cout<<"dist: "<<(5.0 + max(0.0, 50.0 - 10.0 * dist))<<endl;
    return (5.0 + max(0.0, 50.0 - 10.0 * dist)) * 0.0174533;
}

void print(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            cout<<m[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            m[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
    m[(int)player.y][(int)player.x] = 'o';
    m[(int)obstacle.y][(int)obstacle.x] = '@';

    float rad = angle();

    point end(20.0 * (obstacle.x - player.x) + obstacle.x, 20.0 * (player.y - obstacle.y) + obstacle.y);
    point p2 = rotate(obstacle, rad / 2.0, end, true);
    point p3 = rotate(obstacle, rad / 2.0, end, false);

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
            if(i == (int) player.y && j == (int) player.x) continue;
            if(i == (int) obstacle.y && j == (int) obstacle.x) continue;
            if(inside(obstacle, p2, p3, point(j, i))) m[i][j] = '#';
        }
    }

    print();

    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
....o....                                                                                                                                                                          
.........                                                                                                                                                                          
....@....                                                                                                                                                                          
....#....                                                                                                                                                                          
....#....                                                                                                                                                                          
....#....                                                                                                                                                                          
...###...                                                                                                                                                                          
...###...                                                                                                                                                                          
...###...
```

Comment: That's so coool, thank you ! I tried running the code and testing different positions
and there seems to be an issue when player is not on the same column, the "area that can't be seen " is on the wrong side, I've put an example of the output in my post (EDIT)

Comment: I've found another solution which is for every single position, i'm drawing a virtual line between the center of a position and the player, if the obstacle cut between them then it's not "visible"

Comment: Your option is good too, probably much easier to implement than mine. A tip would be to use the matrix as 1x1 squares, considering the obstacle as a circle of radius 0.5 and the player and other slots as points in the center of the 1x1 squares.

Comment: This way, you can just use common geometrical formulas to see if the player vision cuts the obstacle circle.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the player is at (0,0), and the obstacle is at (j,k), with j>0 and k>=0.

Then a square at (x, y) will be visible if either (2j-1)y >= (2k+1)x or (2k-1)x >= (2j+1)y.

Applying this rule to the other three quadrants is straightforward.